# List of 1000, create multiple pages with flask-paginate

Tags: python, html, web, flask, pagination

So I have a list of items say around 1000 and want to create multiple pages using pagination so that all 1000 items does not get listed in one page. How do I go about doing this? I'm currently using flask as the front end framework and tried to use flask-paginate, but it does not seem to work. Can anyone give me guidance? Thanks

```
{{pagination.info | safe}}

{% for user in users %}
<a href=/search/{{user}}>
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="panel-body">
         {{user}}
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
{{pagination.links | safe}}
{% endfor%}
```

python

```
> @app.route('/search/<int:page>')
> def search(page=1):
> page = request.args.get('page', type=int, default=1) 
> users = ['test1','test2', 'test3'] # Should be 1000 values or so 
> pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), search=True, record_name='users') 
> return render_template("search.html", users=users,
>                        search_query=search_query, pagination=pagination,)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all in the route

```
pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(users), search=True, record_name='users')
```

must be corrected to

```
pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=10, search=True, record_name='users')
```

assuming you want 10 items per page.

You can check this link to better understand how to deal with paginations
http://www.ergo.io/blog/better-pagination-in-flask/

Comment: total is total number of items not total number of item per page. To limit items on page, just pass one more param `per_page=<number_of_items_per_page>`